# Why can't I install Flask right way?

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, flask

```
nkb@planet:~$ python3 -m venv venv
Error: Command '['/home/nkb/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']'
returned non-zero exit status 1.
nkb@planet:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

This command solved my problem:

```
python3 -m venv venv --without-pip
```